# How to show Form when button is clicked in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react and trying to create a car portal where on the basis of the availability of a car the user can book a car by clicking on the button. But when I click  the button it shows the form for all available cars, how do I show the form only for the car whose button is clicked?.

Below is my App.js file

```
import React from "react";

const cars = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Mruti",
    price: 5.2,
    available: false,
    rental_price: 5000,
    type: "Hatchback",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Rnault",
    price: 5.2,
    available: true,
    rental_price: 3000,
    type: "SUV",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Adi",
    price: 5.2,
    available: false,
    rental_price: 5000,
    type: "SUV",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Hundai",
    price: 209,
    available: false,
    rental_price: 100000,
    type: "Luxury",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Aton",
    price: 500,
    available: true,
    rental_price: 500000,
    type: "Luxury",
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "Ercedes",
    price: 35,
    available: false,
    rental_price: 50000,
    type: "Sedan",
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "BMW",
    price: 32,
    available: false,
    rental_price: 50000,
    type: "Hatchback",
  },
];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showForm: false };
  }

  showForm = () => {

    
    return (
      <div>
        <form id="add-app">
          <label>Price : </label>
          <input type="text" />

          <label> Hours : </label>
          <input type="text" />

          <button>Book</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  };



  render() {

    
  
    return (
      <div className="product">
        {cars.map((car) => (
          <div class="product_info">
            <p key={car.id}>{car.name}</p>
            <p key={car.id}>{car.price}</p>
            <p key={car.id}>
              {car.available === true ? (
                <>
                  <p>Available</p>
                  <button
                    onClick={() => {
                      this.setState({showForm:true})
                    }}
                    
                  >
                    Rent car
                  </button>
                  {this.state.showForm ? this.showForm() : null}
                </>
              ) : (
                <p>Unavailable</p>
              )}
            </p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a boolean state (`this.setState({ showForm: true })`) you might want to store the car object itself in state (`this.setState({ car })`).

Then you can check if the car in state is not null rather than checking if `showForm` is true, and your `showForm()` method can have access to the currently selected car through the state.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
{this.state.showForm && (<this.showForm />)}
```

Btw, is there any specific reason you're using a functional component inside a class component?

If not I think it's inefficient to have it inside the `App` class since it'll be creating new `showForm` components for each `App` instance.